# submit and refirect user using window.location not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I Have Ajax code That Performs `window.location = "free-listing-new.php";` And Code is as follow

For some reason i cant use `<form action="">`.

```
$("#submitnumber1").submit(function(){

        if ($("#cmobile1").val() != "" && $("#user_selected_country").val() != "" && $("#cmobile1").val().length > 8) 
        {
          var mynumber = $("#cmobile1").val();
          var userCountry = $("#user_selected_country").val();
          //Ajax Call
          $.ajax({
              type : "POST",
              url : "ajax/ajax-send-otp.php",
              data : {mynumber:mynumber,userCountry:userCountry},
              success : function(data) {
                if(data == 2){
                  window.location = "free-listing-new.php";
                }else{
                  alert("Error : " + data);
                }
              }
          });
        }
});
```

And Html is

```
<form  method="post" action="" id="submitnumber1">
</form>
```

Now On Form Submit If Data is 2 Than user should redict to desire page(free-listing) But it cant.php

Comment: check your console for error. and check your ajax response too.

Comment: An empty `action` attribute is the same as `action="<current page>"` and I don't see anything to stop the inital submit event from doing its work.

Comment: i also added `$_REQUEST['PHP_SELF'] ` still `window location` Not Working

Comment: It would work, but you're not stopping the submission of the form. If you open the network tab in the developer tools you will see _two_ POST requests. One for `ajax-send-otp.php` and one for the current page.

Comment: Remove "action" from <form>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350247/how-to-prevent-form-from-being-submitted

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "return false" to your submit-eventhandler.